# C# - Creating a list by filtering a pre-exisitng list

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, linq, xaml

I am very new to C# lists and databases, please keep this in mind.

I have a list of workouts saved in a database that also has the `UserID` field to make each workout added to the table unique to each user. I want to make a list view for when the user logs in, they can see only their workouts.

I have tried to do this by creating a new list without all the workouts that don't have that User's primary key/userID

```cs
public void Read()
{
    using (UserDataContext context = new UserDataContext())
    {
        DatabaseWorkouts = context.Workouts.ToList(); // Saves the users from the database into a list

       // DatabaseWorkouts = context.Workouts.FindAll(item => item.UserID != Globals.primaryKey);   I thought this would work

        foreach (var item in DatabaseWorkouts.ToList())
        {
            if (DatabaseWorkouts.Exists(item => item.UserID != Globals.primaryKey))
            {
                DatabaseWorkouts.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        ItemList.ItemsSource = DatabaseWorkouts; //Displays the list on the listview in the GUI
    }
}
```

I have run many tests with this code above and I think that it only displays the workouts that are most recent and accept conditions, instead of just accepting conditions.

Please help

Comment: Outside of the question (and the answer that says "get the just-right amount of data to begin with" (instead of getting too much data and then filtering out............. Your code is mixing UI elements and DataLayer object (DbContext).  This is a very bad design.  Please start looking into "layered development".   https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fetching all the workouts and then removing the ones that don't belong to the user, you could just directly fetch the user's ones.

Assuming that `Globals.primaryKey` is the targeted user's id, you can do the following

```cs
var userWorkouts = context.Workouts.Where(w => w.UserId == Globals.primaryKey).ToList();

ItemList.ItemsSource = userWorkouts;
```